# Kaltura - Play video on iOS using new Kaltura SDK 1.1

Tags: ios, kaltura

How to play video using Kaltura's new sdk. According old SDK they have provided KPViewController which has method initWithUrl, using which i was able to play video.

```
NSString *tempUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://cdnapisec.kaltura.com/p/243342/sp/24334200/embedIframeJs/uiconf_id/12905712/partner_id/1988382?iframeembed=true&entry_id=%@",entryId];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:tempUrl];

    self.player = [[KPViewController alloc] initWithURL:url];
    self.player.view.frame = [self.viewVideo bounds];
    [self.player loadPlayerIntoViewController:self];
    [self.viewVideo addSubview:self.player.view];
```

but in new SDK which i m installing through POD :
**pod 'player-sdk-native-ios', '~> 1.1'** has KPViewController class but doesnt not have initWithURL method, so how to play video using new SDK ?

Answer (score 0):

We update the documentation here : https://github.com/kaltura/player-sdk-native-ios - please give it a try :-)